# css3 translate in percent

Tags: css, transition

I am stuck on defining an css3 cube completely with percent.

Here a short example in Codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/detAB

As you can see the cube faces have 100% width and height of its parent element, which works perfect. Now i am trying to translate the bottom face 50% down and 50% back.

with pixel values this is no problem

```
transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50px) translateY(50px);
```

but with percent nothing happens

```
transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(50%) translateY(50%);
```

is there any other way? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The percentage there is not of the parent container in the way you might expect but of the element itself. The spec describes it as:

> [The percentage] refer[s] to the size of the element's box

Regarding %s, the spec says:

> Note that  values are not allowed in the **translateZ**
>   translation-value, and if present will cause the propery value to be
>   invalid.

Though, it seems that instead, they aren't valid in any of them for Chrome at least.

Sorry :(

Comment: Something handy I've found is using `em` to use relative distances within `translate` functions. Set the size of `em` in the parent element and then within there, `1em` is 100%, `0.5em` is 50% and so on.

Comment: Can you expand on that jaypeagi?

Comment: this is really useful information. I have been tryiong to use `left: 100%` or `right:100%` to move the element based on its width. but `transform:translate(100%)` was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've found is by doing a bit of javascript.

Instead of using the `translateZ()` value, I've used the **`transform-origin: x y z`** for the axis to be at the center of the cube.

The point is that the cube can turn on its center (and not turn on a center of the main face and translate z...)

Here is the jQuery function (eventually to apply on `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).resize()`) :

```
function get50() {
  var half_width = $('#front').width() / 2;
  $('#front').css({
    transformOrigin : '50% 50% -' + half_width + 'px'
  });
}
```

You can see a **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOppVK)** here...