# how to make a title div center aligned

Tags: css

[UPDATE] It turns out that I can use `transform`, and according to [css3 translate in percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103828/css3-translate-in-percent)
**When using transform with %, it is relative to the element self's box dimension but not its parent.**

---

All:

I wonder how to make a gadget with center aligned text above a round area:

The HTML structure is like:

```css
  .bar {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 300px;
   height: 5px;
   background-color: grey;

   position: absolute;
   top:50px;
   left:50px;
  }
  .tick {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 9px;
   height: 9px;
   background-color: whitesmoke;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-radius: 4px;
   cursor: pointer;

   position: absolute;
   left:10px;
   top: -2px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .title {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 100%;
   background-color: whitesmoke;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   width: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
   border-radius:2px;
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
   -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
   -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
   -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
   -ms-user-select: none;       /* IE/Edge */
   user-select: none;  
  }
```

```html
 <div class="bar">
  <span class="tick">
   <span class="title">6/1/2015</span>
  </span>
 </div>
```

**I want the title center align with that round circle down below. Is there a simple way to do that in CSS**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `transform`

```
.title {
    ...
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

For greater compatibility use `-webkit-transform` and `-ms-transform`.  See the compatibility charts here: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

```css
.bar {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 300px;
   height: 5px;
   background-color: grey;

   position: absolute;
   top:50px;
   left:50px;
  }
  .tick {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 9px;
   height: 9px;
   background-color: whitesmoke;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border-radius: 4px;
   cursor: pointer;

   position: absolute;
   left:10px;
   top: -2px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .title {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 100%;
   background-color: whitesmoke;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   width: auto;
   white-space: nowrap;
   border-radius:2px;
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
   -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
   -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
   -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
   -ms-user-select: none;       /* IE/Edge */
   user-select: none;  
            transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <span class="tick">
   <span class="title">6/1/2015</span>
  </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is cool!  But why margin-left: -50% not work, but translateX(-50%); does?

Comment: @Kuan I assume this falls under the statement "[margin] percentages [are] calculated based on the containing block" ([W3C Documenaton](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins) on computing margins).  Basically, because the containing block is the 7px element, a percentage value will result in a percentage of that containing block's width.  That results in a margin of 3.5px for a 50% margin.

Comment: Thanks, this is new knowledge to me, I thought margin and transform are both based on their parent box dimension when using %, but actually the transform not. This is cool

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad I could help, and I would have made the same assumption too.  Unfortunately margins (ones using percentages especially) have been very confusing in CSS historically.

Comment: Thanks,  another question related to this design is how to handle mousedown/move/up correctly to implement a drag action, my current design is mousedown: bind mousemove to document, calc the offset using clientX and remove mousemove  on mouseup. But I feel this may cause event confliction with other event handler(but not sure), just wonder if there is other way to handle it gracefuly

Comment: @Kuan Apologies for the late reply. I was smashed. For that kind of situation, you usually want to tie the event to the element itself (the circle or the bar or both). I would ask why  you feel the need to attach it to the document.  It's not impossible, but most of the time it's unnecessary. To answer you directly, there is potential for conflict attaching to the document, but it can be done without conflicts. I would need more information, however to help further.  Hit me up in this message tomorrow if you have any issues with it and I see what I can do to help.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I bind the mouse move to document is because if I used to bind the event to that circle area or the title, but when I move the cursor fast and go out of its area, the move event will not work

Comment: @Kuan.  I see.  In that case, you don't want to bind to mousemove.  You want to bind to mousedown and mouseup.  On mousedown you set a toggle indicating that you're dragging.  You also want a mouseup toggle (that one can be bound to the document).  When that one is triggered, it unsets that indicating toggle.  That way you aren't relying on the mouse being over the circle for it to work.