# move element based on its own width

Tags: css

I have been working on something where I wanted to move *(and animate later)* the position of an element based on its own width and I wanted to use pure CSS with it. I have tried multiple things but couldn't figure out the solution.

I initially, tried using `left: 50%`, but the percentage here is according to the parent.

Then I had to rely on JavaScript. I was able to figure it out using JavaScript (below code). But I would like to do this without JS

```js
const child = document.getElementById("child");
child.style.left = child.offsetWidth + "px"
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: @Moderators, the question linked as duplicate here isn't an actual duplicate. Just the answer is related - but the root questions are completely different. Here I talk about how `left: 50%` is different to `transform: translateX(50%)`. The linked question simply focuses on translate. I added this question and answer here  - referring to the linked question. Because when I was searching for this problem, I couldn't find a relevant question/answer

Comment: Closing does not mean it is deleted, it is to stop further answers from being posted.  I don't see any reason to vote to reopen it.  And you should really have posted the javascript here, there is a built-in snippet tool.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I found that I can use CSS `transform: translateX(100%)` to move the position of an element based on its own width.

```css
.parent1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.child1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

.parent2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.child2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child1"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104099/6908282) which talks about the similar thing

Answer (score -1):

Remember, if you using percent. With `top - left - bottom - right`, its according to parent width. But with `translate`, its according to current element.

When you make element to `left 50%`, your left edge stay at `50%` not your center element. So all we need is push there center to this position with `translateX(-50%)`. This is also the popular way to make element center `(top, left: 50%, translate(-50%, -50%)`

```css
#parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
<br>
```